# PHP script not inserting a value into the database

Tags: php, mysqli

Below I have a modules drop down menu where it gets a list of modules from the db an obviously displays them in a drop down menu:

```
$active = 1;

 $sql = "SELECT ModuleId, ModuleNo, ModuleName FROM Module WHERE ModuleActive = ? ORDER BY ModuleNo"; 

 $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

 $sqlstmt->bind_param("i",$active);

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 

 $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName);

 $modules = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

 $output = ""; 
 $moduleHTML = "";  
 $moduleHTML .= '<select name="module" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
 $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
 { 
     $moduleno = $dbModuleNo;
     $module = $dbModuleId;
     $modulename = $dbModuleName; 
     $moduleHTML .= "<option value='".$module."'>" . $moduleno . " - " . $modulename . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  

         if (isset($_POST['module']) && ($_POST['module'] == $module)) {
    $output .= "<p><strong>Selected Module:</strong> " . $moduleno .  " - "  . $modulename . "</p>";
}
  } 

  $moduleHTML .= '</select>';
```

But the problem I am getting below is that when I try to insert the selected module into the database, it is unable to do it and hence ModuleId is null. Why can it not insert the selected module into the database?

```
if (isset($_POST['module'])) {

$_SESSION['module'] = $_POST['module'];

}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

{



            $insertsql = "
      INSERT INTO Session
        (ModuleId)
      VALUES
        (?)
    ";
    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }


        $insert->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['module']);

        $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insert->close();



}
```

ModuleId is an INT field

Comment: Unable or not happening? Is there an error popping up or just does nothing happen. Use debugging to test expected things.

Comment: First, why are you using prepared statements?

Comment: Can you do parameter binding without using prepared statements?

Comment: Where is you form tag that specifies the `POST`?

Comment: @zeyorama Prepared statements are safer, faster, and the future.

Comment: If you want a secure sql query, use the `real_escape_string($query)` to be safe for sql-injections. Faster only, if you are execute this query more than one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    if ($insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {


    $insert->bind_param("i", real_escape_string($_SESSION['module']));

    $insert->execute();
    $insert->close();
    }
    else  {
      // Handle query error here
    }
```